Relative Error vs. Absolute Error in different glassware
Why, for some glassware (such as graduated cylinders and burets) is the absolute error constant throughout the instrument and the relative error is dependant on the measured volume, while for other glassware (such as beakers and Erlenmeyer flasks) the relative error is constant throughout the instrument and the absolute error is dependant upon the measured volume?
Thanks

Before asking why, always check if. Aside of that, beakers and E. flasks are not intended to measure volumes. Their volume marks are just for orientation. // Review the guide How to ask and Asking FAQs to prevent clarification requests, objections,  downvoting or closure.

Consider different sources of error. For example, the error due to meniscus is invariant whether a cylinder is one-quarter or three-quarters full,  but error due to temperature effects on liquid and on container might vary with volume.
